# Trigonometry proof

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Question:
$$2\cos x -\cos 3x - \cos 5x = 16\cos^3 x\sin^2 x$$

What I have tried:
Using the identities, I have converted all the cos and sin so that the angle inside is only $x$. However, I couldn't proceed by simplifying and the equation got too complicated. I must be missing something, which would make the question surprisingly easy...

Please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Using the trigonometric sum and difference angle identities we have (the last expression involves factorising out the common factor $2\cos x$)
$$2\cos x -\cos 3x - \cos 5x = 2\cos x - (\cos 3x + \cos 5x )\\=2\cos x - 2\cos x\cos 4x=2\cos x(1-\cos 4x)$$
This is because (have a look at the "angle sum and difference identities" in [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/idents.htm)) we have
$$\cos 5x = \cos (4x+x)=\color{green}{\cos 4x\cos x} - \sin 4x \sin x$$
$$\cos 3x = \cos (4x-x)=\color{green}{\cos 4x\cos x} + \sin 4x \sin x$$
Adding the above two equations leads to the cancellation of the sine terms, resulting in
$$\cos 5x + \cos 3x=\color{green}{2\cos 4x\cos x}$$
Applying the double angle formula for $\cos 4x$ then $\sin 2x$ as below, results in
$$2\cos x(1-\color{blue}{\cos 4x})=2\cos x(1-\color{blue}{(1-2\sin^22x)})=4\cos x\color{red}{\sin^22x}\\=4\cos x\color{red}{(2\sin x\cos x)^2}=16\cos^3x\sin^2x$$

Comment: I don't see how you combined cox3x and cox5x. Can you please explain?

Comment: I have elaborated my answer to show how to combine the $\cos 3x$ and $\cos 5x$ terms. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how cos3x + cos5x can become 2cosxcos4x and how that becomes 1-cos4x, guess an identity I never learnt

Comment: @Cookies you hate trignometry.Don't you? You have seen the identity and its there. you are just not able to see it.

Comment: @Sid How were you able to deduce that I hate trigonometry? Well unfortunately it is true. One of the subjects that I can rarely ever understand. I find it difficult to prove anything in trigonometry.

Comment: Well, I looked at the question you posted yesterday. It was not very difficult to understand that you are having hard time understanding that subject. I agree, trigonometry is difficult to understand, but not impossible. you need to tilt your head a little (_not literally_) to look for identities in trigonometry! good luck. :) (no offence)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3x - 3\cos x$ and $\cos 5x = 5\cos x - 20\cos^3 x + 16\cos^5 x$, substituting those on the left-hand side and simplifying gives
$$16\cos^3 x - 16\cos^5 x = 16\cos^3x(1-\cos^2 x) = 16\cos^3x\sin^2 x.$$

Comment: Oh... I see. But there's an identity for $\cos 5x$ ??

Comment: Just figure it out by expanding. Or, do what I did: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=cos+5x+in+terms+of+cos+x

Comment: Haha I see. That's a nice website

Comment: @Cookies You can derive these types of formulas by using [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula) and comparing the real and imaginary parts of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euler's formula to get
$e^{ix}+e^{-ix} - {1 \over 2} (e^{i3x}+e^{-i3x} ) - {1 \over 2} (e^{i5x}+e^{-i5x} ) $ on the left hand side.

On the right hand side we have (using $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$ to simplify):
$  (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^3 (2-{1 \over 2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^2) = 
(e^{i3x}+ 3e^{ix} + 3 e^{-ix} + e^{-i3x} ) (1  -{1\over 2} e^{i2x} -{1\over 2} e^{-2x}) $.

Carrying out the tedious multiplication shows that they are the same.

Comment: Well.... I think the others have provided a much easier method. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

For Details check all the trignometric identities [here](http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/trigonometric-identities.htm)

$2\cos  x-\left(\cos  3x+\cos  5x\right)$

$\implies 2\cos  x-\left(2\cos  x.\cos  4x\right)$

$\implies 2\cos  x\left(1-\cos  4x\right)$

$\implies 2\cos  x(1-\left(1-2\sin ^2 2x\right)$

$\implies 4\cos  x\left(\sin ^2 2x\right)$

$\implies 4\cos  x\left(\left(2\sin  x\cos  x\right)^2\right)$

$\implies 16\cos ^3 x\sin ^2 x$

Comment: Okay, I understood the process, but lost you in the identities. How did you combine cos3x and cox5x. And how did 2cosxcos4x convert to 1 - cos4x?

Comment: Okay, so you can represent 5x as 4x+x and 3x as 4x-x. This gives us 2 definite A and B in the form of x and 4x. Then you can apply $cos A cos B =½[cos (A + B) + cos (A-B)]$

Comment: Look at the link I provided and you will have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=2\cos x-\cos3x-\cos5x=(\cos x-\cos3x)+(\cos x-\cos5x)$$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula, $\displaystyle\cos C-\cos D$,

$$I=2\sin x\sin2x+2\sin2x\sin3x=2\sin2x(\sin x+\sin3x)$$

and using $\displaystyle\sin C+\sin D$ formula, $$\sin x+\sin3x=2\sin2x\cos x$$

Finally use $\displaystyle\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

Comment: @Cookies, How about this?